# Splitting a csv column into two columns (powershell)

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a csv with rows of addresses where some have apt numbers and some don't. I've been using powershell to try to split the column into two. One for the address and one for the apartment. 
So the initial column looks like this.

```
839 Main St Apt 3
130 Marcy Ave
399 Broadway Ave Apt 6F
```

The result I'm looking for

**Address column**

```
839 Main St                 
130 Marcy Ave
399 Broadway Ave
```

**Apartment Column**

Apt 3 
blank space
Apt 6F

I'm trying to see how I would be able to split this. If I use a space as the delimiter, then it'll break up the adderess column into multiple columns. If I use the letter A then ill be left with pt 6F for example. What would be the right way to tackle this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dirty data is always an issue. If the 'Apt' abbreviation is always used, then you could split on that.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Is there a way to split it based on that word and still keep it? I was thinking of appending the missing letters that get chopped off if I use the split function, but not every row has the APT in it. In excel, I would append ~ infront of APT using search and replace, then use text to columns and use ~ as the delimiter. I don't know how I'd go about doing that via powershell.

Comment: Yes, you would need to split on the word (including the spaces around it) and add Apt back to the second bit after the split. You would also need to use some logic to handle lines without it.

Comment: Simple solution could be  `-split"(Apt.*)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$aptReg=[regex]'^(.*)(Apt.*)$'
"839 Main St Apt 3","130 Marcy Ave","399 Broadway Ave Apt 6F" | % {if($aptReg.IsMatch($_)){$a=$aptReg.Matches($_);[PSCustomObject]@{"A1"=$a.Groups[1].Value;"A2"=$a.Groups[2].Value}}else{[PSCustomObject]@{"A1"=$_;"A2"=""}}}
```

It gives :

```
A1                     A2                                                                                                                              
--                     --                                                                                                                              
839 Main St            Apt 3                                                                                                                           
130 Marcy Ave                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
399 Broadway Ave       Apt 6F
```

---

Given the following CSV file :

```
"Name","Surname","Address","Zipcode"
"N1","S1","839 Main St Apt 3","Z1"
"N2","S2","130 Marcy Ave","Z2"
"N2","S2","399 Broadway Ave Apt 6F","Z2"
```

A very long one liner ...

Import-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv | % {if($aptReg.IsMatch($*.Address)){$a=$aptReg.Matches($*.address);$a1=$a.Groups[1].Value;$a2=$a.Groups[2].Value}else{$a1=$*.address;$a2=""};Add-Member -InputObject $* -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "A1" -Value $a1;Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "A2" -Value $a2;$_} | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\test Bis.csv"

Comment: Great! Thank you!. this is exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm very very new to powershell, so i do have another question. I'm pulling the info from a csv using Import-CSV with other columns. So I'm trying to figure out how I would modify this to fit that scenario. I'm assuming where we have the addresses manually listed here, is where I would load my data and run the $aptReg against the initial address column. Will this populate two new columns A1 & A2 (In my case Address and Apartment)

Comment: You have to use Add-Member cmdlet to add the result. I edit my answer.

Comment: So it does exactly what it's suppose to do for the 1st row. the next following rows it doesn't parse the address but appends @{Address= the full address; A1=; A2=} In to column A1

Comment: Corrected ... I suppose so.